# Book choices django

Tags: django, templates

My models:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    # book types and placed
    BIOGRAFIA = 1
    FANTASTYKA = 2
    HISTORYCZNY = 3
    HORROR = 4
    POEZJA = 5
    PRZYGODA = 6
    ROMANS = 7
    DRAMAT = 8
    BRAK = 0
    B00K_CHOICES = (
        (BIOGRAFIA, 'Biografia'),
        (FANTASTYKA, 'Fantasy/Sci-Fi'),
        (HISTORYCZNY, 'Historyczny'),
        (HORROR, 'Horror'),
        (POEZJA, 'Poezja'),
        (PRZYGODA, 'Przygoda'),
        (ROMANS, 'Romans'),
        (DRAMAT, 'Dramat'),
        (BRAK, 'Brak informacji'),
    )
    gatunek = models.IntegerField(choices=B00K_CHOICES, default=BRAK)
```

My views:

```
@login_required
def gatunek_lista(request):
    ksiazki = Book.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'ksiazki.html', {'ksiazki': ksiazki, 'gatunek': Book.B00K_CHOICES})
```

My template:

For sure something is wrong here

```
for gatunek in B00K_CHOICES:
                                print(choice)

                                    ('Biografia', 1, 'Biografia'),
                                    ('FANTASTYKA', 2, 'Fantasy/Sci-Fi'),
                                    ('HISTORYCZNY', 3, 'Historyczny'),
                                    ('HORROR', 4, 'Horror'),
                                    ('POEZJA', 5, 'Poezja'),
                                    ('PRZYGODA', 6, 'Przygoda'),
                                    ('ROMANS', 7, 'Romans'),
                                    ('DRAMAT', 8, 'Dramat'),
```

I have a question, how to make my template (html) show all options = B00K CHOICE
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your template should look like this:

```
{% for key, gatunek in B00K_CHOICES %}

    <p>{{ gatunek }}</p>

{% endfor %}
```

Find out more about `for` template tag in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for)

Answer (score 0):

```
views.py 

@login_required
def gatunek_lista(request):
    ksiazki = Book.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'ksiazki.html', {'ksiazki': ksiazki, 'gatunek': ksiazki})


# You have iterate over the object which you are passing to your template

{% for ksiazki_obj in ksiazki %}
    {% for book_choices in ksiazki_obj.gatunek %}
        {{ book_choices }} 
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Do you have any data in your model or table?

Comment: Yes, I have added several books

Comment: Have you edited your view function, like I have done in my answer?

Comment: Yes I changed, my vievs.py

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for ksiazki in ksiazki  %}


                            {% for book_choices in ksiazki_obj.gatunek %}
                                {{ book_choices }}

                                   <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">('Biografia', 1, 'Biografia')</li>
                                   <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">('FANTASTYKA', 2, 'Fantasy/Sci-Fi')</li>
                                   <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">('HISTORYCZNY', 3, 'Historyczny')</li>
                                   <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">('HORROR', 4, 'Horror')</li>
                                   <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">('POEZJA', 5, 'Poezja')</li>
                                   <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">('PRZYGODA', 6, 'Przygoda')</li>
                                   <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">('ROMANS', 7, 'Romans')</li>
                                   <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">('DRAMAT', 8, 'Dramat')</li>

                            {% endfor %}



{% endfor %}
```

Comment: My Full template.